# C++: Checking for NULL on delete

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Test for void pointer in C++ before deleting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844374/test-for-void-pointer-in-c-before-deleting)

Is code snippet 1 equivalent to snippet 2?

```
//Snippet 1:
    delete record;          
    record = new Record;


//Snippet 2     
    if (record != NULL) 
    {
        delete record;
        record = NULL;
    }       
    record = new Record;
```

Comment: duplicates (only the 1st page of results, there are many more): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/615355/is-there-any-reason-to-check-for-a-null-pointer-before-deleting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190703/is-it-safe-to-delete-a-null-pointer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821261/null-check-before-deleting-an-object http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724688/how-many-of-you-are-aware-that-its-safe-to-delete-a-null-pointer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558013/delete-null-but-no-compile-error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844374/test-for-void-pointer-in-c-before-deleting

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only difference I can see is that if the `Record` constructor throws an exception, the first sample might leave the `record` variable set to the old deleted value, whereas in the second, it will be set to `NULL`.

EDIT:
Indeed the first sample, if repeated later, would lead to a double delete.

```
delete record;
record = new Record; // Throwing exception
// record points to old object
// ... later ...
delete record; // Double deletion - sky falls down etc.
```

The safe form would be:

```
delete record; record = 0;
record = new Record; // Can throw an exception if it likes
```

Or use a `std::auto_ptr` instead of a raw pointer.

Comment: ... which might lead to a double-delete issue, as James pointed out (just adding for completeness).

Answer (score 6):

It depends on the scope of record. If it's a class member and is deleted in the destructor then no, they're not the same. The first version can leave you with a double-delete issue (if new Record() throws) because record is not NULL.

If it has function-level scope then I think the second version is overkill.

The second version is more safe.

Comment: good catch. You might want to mention that this is in the case where the Record constructor throws and it's about assigning 0 to the pointer, not about the check for null before deleting.

Comment: +1 for spotting what the questioner and all the close-voters missed: the title doesn't reflect the body of the question.

Answer (score 3):

They are the same in that you have a new Record at the end of each, but snippet two has an unnecessary check for NULL prior to the delete.

Answer (score 1):

The `delete` operator in C++ is required to work correctly (do nothing) when the pointer is NULL, so the two code fragments are the same.  See http://opensource.devx.com/tips/Tip/14443, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is: `delete` on a NULL pointer is expected to work as in your latter code.

See $ 5.3.5:

> 2 If the operand has a class type, the
>   operand is converted to a pointer type
>   by calling the above-mentioned
>   conversion function, and the converted
>   operand is used in place of the
>   original operand for the remainder of
>   this section. In either alternative,
>   the value of the operand of delete may
>   be a null pointer value.

Answer (score 1):

A nitpicking answer: The result is the same IF record is a pointer to record (with the caveats described in the other posts wrt. the record constructor throwing). If it's a class type with an implicit conversion to a pointer, the result might not be the same (because operators might be overloaded.)